# Why is my entity becoming null after a while

Tags: primefaces, cdi

I have a `Claim` entity in `ClaimsController`. `ClaimsController` is annotated with `@ConversationScope @Named`. After a little while the claim object becomes null but the session hasn't expired yet. Does anyone have an idea why? If I was editing and the claim object becomes `null`, `ClaimsController` goes ahead and creates a new row instead of editing the original.

Comment: Please add a [mcve]

Comment: And check if there is a cdi manager logging or something to see what happens... And check with a minimal/plain jsf (instead of PrimeFaces)